# How does this pure CSS tab work?

Tags: css

Just came across this by Chris Coyier - http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSSTabs/

Can anyone explain me, how does the class .cur get applied to a tab's heading, when we click it? There's no js in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's relying on the CSS3 selector :target. Target are for sections within an html page, like http://www.example.com/page#section (SO uses them to jump to specific answers).

When the target is selected, the target pseudo class take over.

Here it's using z-index tricks to push the sections up and down on top of each other.

That's the general gist of it, I don't know the specifics.

Edit --

The "cur" class isn't applied at all. On the right, each "pane" has all three tabs defined in them, but with the "cur" class "hardcoded" for each pane. The z-indexing brings up the entire pane, with it tabs, to the top, creating the effect. When in fact, it's just 3 divs of HTML.

So there's no magic here (beyond the whole :target pseudo class).

Comment: There are no specifics exept: the `:target` selects the current visible tab. Each tab also contains it's tab-headers. And then it applies a `cur` class to the `li` that is currently "selected".

Comment: I was wondering how did the class `.cur` get applied to the element (when clicked). Could you point me to the line of css code that did it?

Comment: @Anant read Will's link. The trick is `:target`. I head to read it a few times too until I understood it.

Comment: May be helpful - http://www.decodize.com/css/css3-target-pseudo-class-pure-css-based-tab-lightbox-notification/